# Auto create database and tables when first run the server in spring Hibernate with out do any operation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

how can I auto create database and tables when first run the server in spring Hibernate with out do any operation ? 
Here is my xml file. but not creating db. if already db is there,This code is auto creating table when first operation I will do. At least I need auto create tables at first start the server.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />
    </bean>
<bean id="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory"        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>                   
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>     
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Exceptions are as bellow

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    com.fidzeal.fivebar.dao.RegUserDAOImpl.save(RegUserDAOImpl.java:35)
    com.fidzeal.fivebar.HomeController.registercontroll(HomeController.java:271)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'test')
```

Comment: You're giving your `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property a value twice. Which one do you want, `create` or `update`?

Comment: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property a value twice. Because if I will insert any row, It is replacing previous row data. If I will write create and update  both, then it is adding new row  at time of insert data

Comment: Properties can only have a single value, so that won't work.

Comment: check http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/03/spring-hibernate-integration-tutorial.html  it may help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your database in known state when you deploy the app then use:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

If you just want to generate the db schema use:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

In your xml you've specified the property twice.

Other thing is:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database 'test')
```

Unknown database 'test' - have you created a db called test ?

I strongly recommend testing you connection using some independent tool. For instance you can add you jdbc url in intellij's database view and check whether it's correct.

Comment: I have alrady tried the property   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop. but it is not creating db.

Comment: If I am creating db test manually. It is working fine, there is no exception. I need auto create db at time of deploy. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh I see. You need to both create the db and generate the schema. I'm not sure but I think you have to have the db created.

Comment: OK thank You. I need this table should create at time of deploy. It is creating, when I will use first time. Can you help on this ?